# jQuery carousel, create button 'on click go to slide x'

Tags: jquery, pagination, slider, carousel

I'm working on a page with tabbed panels. underneath these panels I'm viewing an infinite carousel slideshow. whenever i click on a tab i would like that the images inside the would align with the content of the tab.

I have an id for the tabs and I have id's for the slideshow images so I need a function that whenever I click on tab 1, the carousel automatically scrolls to for example slide1.

the function should be similar or the same as a pager or pagination for a slider/carousel

I'm working on this to happen for a few days, but i'm completely new to jquery and i can't get my head wrapped around how to write the function and variables.

does anyone knows in which direction to look, or what functions and variables are needed, or whether it is even possible with the current setup?

Thanks in advance

HTML

```
      <div id="carousel">
<div id="buttons">
    <a href="#" id="prev">prev</a>
    <a href="#" id="next">next</a>
</div>


<div id="slides"> 
    <ul>
        <li id="slide1"><img src="images/slide1.png" id="slide1" alt="Slide 1"/></li>
        <li id="slide2"><img src="images/slide2.png" id="slide2" alt="Slide 2"/></li>
        <li id="slide3"><img src="images/slide3.png" id="slide3" alt="Slide 3"/></li>
        <li id="slide4"><img src="images/slide4.png" id="slide4" alt="Slide 4"/></li>
        <li id="slide5"><img src="images/slide5.png" id="slide5" alt="Slide 5"/></li>
        <li id="slide6"><img src="images/slide6.png" id="slide6" alt="Slide 6"/></li>
        <li id="slide7"><img src="images/slide7.png" id="slide7" alt="Slide 7"/></li>
        <li id="slide8"><img src="images/slide8.png" id="slide8" alt="Slide 8"/></li>

    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //rotation speed and timer
var speed = 5000;
var run = setInterval('rotate()', speed);   

//grab the width and calculate left value
var item_width = $('#slides li').outerWidth(); 
var left_value = item_width * (-1); 

//move the last item before first item, just in case user click prev button
$('#slides li:first').before($('#slides li:last'));

//set the default item to the correct position 
$('#slides ul').css({'left' : left_value});

//if user clicked on prev button
$('#prev').click(function() {

    //get the right position            
    var left_indent = parseInt($('#slides ul').css('left')) + item_width;

    //slide the item            
    $('#slides ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 500,function(){    

        //move the last item and put it as first item               
        $('#slides li:first').before($('#slides li:last'));           

        //set the default item to correct position
        $('#slides ul').css({'left' : left_value});

    });

    //cancel the link behavior            
    return false;

});


//if user clicked on next button
$('#next').click(function() {

    //get the right position
    var left_indent = parseInt($('#slides ul').css('left')) - item_width;       

    //slide the item
    $('#slides ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 500, function () {

        //move the first item and put it as last item
        $('#slides li:last').after($('#slides li:first'));                  

        //set the default item to correct position
        $('#slides ul').css({'left' : left_value});

    });

    //cancel the link behavior
    return false;
  });    
});
```

CSS

```
#carousel {
width:896px;
height:172px;    
margin:0 auto;
}

#slides {
overflow:hidden;/* fix ie overflow issue */
position:relative;
width:896px;
height:172px;
border:none;
float:left;
}

/* remove the list styles, width : item width * total items */    
#slides ul {
left:-250px;
top:0;
list-style-type:none;
padding:0px;    
width:9999px;
position:relative;            
}

 /* width of the item, in this case I put 250x250x gif */
#slides li {
width:296px;
height:172px;    
float:left;
padding:0px;
}

#slides li img {
padding:0px;
margin:0 23px 0 23px;
}

/* Styling for prev and next buttons */
#buttons {
padding:0 0 0 0;  
position:relative;  
}

#buttons a {
display:block; 
width:43px; 
height:70px;
text-indent:-999em;
float:left;
outline:0;
}
```

Comment: give a look at http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/ a very good carousel plugin for JQuery. It has a lot of features, methods, events... and it's well documented

Comment: TCHdvlp, I downloaded jcarousel and integrated it on my page. i made a configuration, and you were right, quite easy. the wrap is configured as "circular" so it works the same as my code above, but i still cant figure out with what function is i can make a button to slide to a certain slide of the carousel

Comment: these four tabs should be linked to the slideshow, so that whenever a tab is clicked, the slideshow automaticly moves                       <div id="TabbedPanels1" class="TabbedPanels">
  
    <ul class="TabbedPanelsTabGroup">
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" id="over">over</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" id="man">man</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" id="advi">advi</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" id="conn" >conn</li>
   </ul>

Comment: @TCHdvlp could you be of any help on this?

Comment: @TCHdvlp I also found the scroll element in the docs. But i'm really not even remotely understanding how i can link the function to a particular tab and slide. for example, if i want the tab with the id=conn linked to slide 8, what would the code look like and were would i put it when it should happen on click?

Comment: Immediatly, I see two options. First, your tabs and images in the carousel are ordered. Find the position of the clicked tab and get the corresponding carousel item. Option 2, you want to make things more clean, give a particular ID to your tabs, like `conn-1` for the first element

Answer (score 0):

let me look for it in the doc... (2 mins later) ok, http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/api.html#carousel-related-methods look at the methods, the first one is `scroll`. Doc says : "`.jcarousel('scroll', target [, animate [, callback]])`
Scrolls to a specific item or relative by a given offset"